# Generate alphabetical/digit string with fixed length

Tags: java

My goal is to generate iterative alphabetical/digit string with fixed length, for instance:

```
aaaaaa
aaaaab
aaaaac
...
aaaaa9
aaaaba
...
999999
```

It can be easily implemented with nested for loops, like code below:

```
   public static void main(String[] strings) {
        Object[] array = new Object[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                'y', 'z', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList();
        int a, b, c, d, e, f;
        for (a = 0; a < 35; a++) {
            for (b = 0; b < 35; b++) {
                for (c = 0; c < 35; c++) {
                    for (d = 0; d < 35; d++) {
                        for (e = 0; e < 35; e++) {
                            for (f = 0; f < 35; f++) {
                                list.add("" + array[a] + array[b] + array[c] + array[d] + array[e] + array[f]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it would be good to know how it can be refactored to have for instance possibility to run such code in multiply threads or even some library already exist in order to generate such number.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: May be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is right place for this.

Comment: what you need is still unclear.. when you say fixed length of string containing either alphabets or numbers or both? what is required? and yes definitely can be optimized instead of 5 nested loops'

Comment: Hi Shreyas Sarvothama, thanks for prompt questions. So the main idea is to have fixed lenght of string as it was shown in example. Length should be equals to 6. String can contains both alphabetical and digit characters

Comment: Note that it is better to use char literals rather than mixing your types and using `Object[]`: `char[] array = {'a', 'b', ..., '0', '1', '2'..., '9'};`

Comment: The other thing to ask back: **why** do you want to that? You see, when you think further: there is a direct mapping between any number from 0 to 1838... to each and any of your strings (and for the record: starting with such a string, you can also determine the loop index). So, in essence: what is the point of generating a huge amount of strings - what will you be using them for?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are generating 35^6=1838265625 values; so you can rewrite it using a single for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1838265625; ++i) {
  int ii = i;
  int f = ii % 35; ii /= 35;
  int e = ii % 35; ii /= 35;
  int d = ii % 35; ii /= 35;
  // ...
  int a = ii % 35;

  list.add("" + array[a] + array[b] + array[c] + array[d] + array[e] + array[f]);
}
```

So, to rewrite in multiple threads, just divide up the range `[0..1838265625)` between your threads, so each thread runs a for loop for a portion of that range, e.g. thread 1 does `[0..1_000_000)`, thread 2 does `[1_000_000..2_000_000)` etc.

You might find it easier to use a [`ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) to manage the splitting and joining of the ranges, rather than attempting to do it by hand.

---

Of course, I'm still thinking in pre-Java 8 terms. You can also do it with streams (as suggested by GhostCat):

```
IntStream.range(0, 1838265625).parallelStream()
    .map(i -> {
        int ii = i;
        int f = ii % 35; ii /= 35;
        int e = ii % 35; ii /= 35;
        int d = ii % 35; ii /= 35;
        // ...
        int a = ii % 35;
        return "" + array[a] + array[b] + array[c] + array[d] + array[e] + array[f]; })
    .collect(someCollector);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andy for prompt response, will try both options with  ForkJoinPool and with java 8!!!

Comment: @fashuser try Java 8 first.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Is `i /= 35` should be `ii /= 35`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 50 points to comment, so posting as an answer.

Why the need for so much nested loops? 2 loops would have been sufficient. Calculate the length of the array, store it in `length`

Like

```
for (i=0;i<length;i++)
 {
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
   {
       //what to do
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code could be transformed into a solution using java8 streams. And then you could simply go from a stream() based solution to parallelStream() solution.

The downside is that streams only work with reference types / collections; so you might loose performance by not using the raw char arrays.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to get all permutations of 35 chars in at six places I believe that you'll get StackOverflowException because that will be a list with 1'838'265'625 entries with at least 12 bytes each which is 20GB of memory.
- Secondly use char array because ints have 4 bytes while char is only 2 (unicode).
- At last in concatenations int will outbox to Integer and try to cast to char and I think that you'll get ASCII representation of that int (eg. 1 is "start of heading", a non-printing character)
- If u want bounded random generator of words of fixed length then you can use

```
private static final String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x",
            "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

public List<String> randomWords(int numOfWords, int lengthOfWord){
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
     for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
         list.add(randomWord(lengthOfWord));

     return list;
}

private String randomWord(int lengthOfWord){
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfWord; i++){
        sb.append(array[rand.nextInt(35)]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hint: answers without any explanations ... simply not a good approach. Helping people is much more than just dropping code on them!

Comment: Why introduce randomness? OP isn't asking for "some" values, he is asking for *all* values.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, but my PM stopped me in the middle of writing an answer. I introduce randomness because i realize that he don't  have valid goal due to memory shortage.